# Add document is queried but not added on the console nor listener is called

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Ok I am a running into a weird problem with firestore

I have the following structure
collection1 -> document1- >collection2

I am adding a new document to collection2 with on complete listener( I tried the success listener as well).  No errors are shown. The new document is not shown on the console. The listener is not being called. However, when  I query, I get ALL the added documents including the new ones. What's going on here?

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("completed", true;
data.put("date_completed", new Date()); 
data.put("location", "123 main st");
data.put("notes", "");
data.put("work", "");

db.collection("collection1").document(document1).collection("collection2")
        .add(data)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentReference documentReference = task.getResult();
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                    det.setDocId(documentReference.getId());
                    addr_arr.add(det);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EditListActivity.this, "Failed operation - " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the query I do

```
CollectionReference collecRef = db.collection("collection1").document(document1).collection("collection2");
        collecRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                         // here I do document.get on all the fields, add them to object and add object to array
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EditListActivity.this, "Failed operation - " + task.getException(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: When you say "However, when I query...", what exactly does that mean?  Where is this query?

Comment: I added the Query above. Bascially I do get on all the documents under that collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is acting like it's offline or somehow lacking a working internet connection.

When there is no network connection, the Firestore SDK won't fail on writes.  It will store the write locally, and eventually sync that to the server.  In the meantime, the local write becomes part of any queries, just like if the data was available on the server.  So probably what you're seeing is the result of your local write.

(This is the same behavior you would see with Realtime Database.)

As far why the Firestore SDK doesn't have a connection, I don't know.  You might have to troubleshoot that on your own.

Comment: Wow!! You are right. I am in a cafe placing (cofee and coding, cant get better!) and I do have connection but it was taking long time for queries. Seems unstable. I switched to my phone hotspot and indeed the writes happened and all worked fine. Never knew cache was involved. Is there anyways I can "detect" when the write is cache vs online so I can inform the user? otherwise he would think it wrote to db and other users quering that will not see it

Comment: No, not really.  Part of the benefit of the local cache is that the app appears to be very fast with its writes from the user's point of view, and they don't have to wait to see their own stuff they wrote.  If you want to know when the write actually hits the server, respond to the Task completion.

Comment: You can also detect if your query is getting data from the local cache, by checking the `querySnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache()`.

Comment: @DougStevenson in the above code the whole listener is not hit when adding data so task.isSuccessful() is not hit. Unless you mean something else by task completion

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen that would be helpful I guess in certain situations

Comment: The Task (the thing returned by `add()`) should have its completion and success callbacks invoked when the write completes at the server.  If you're seeing that they *never* get called, that sounds like an issue.

Comment: The only thing to keep in mind there is that task completion listeners are not persisted to disk, so won't survive app restarts. So if you restart the app while the write was still pending in the local cache, the write **will** eventually make it to the server, but the completion listener **won't** fire.